# Why does my .NET Core Web API (deployed on AWS Lambda) return a 502 Bad Gateway error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-webapi, rds

I am new to .NET Core, Entity Framework, AWS, and pretty much everything here (please comment and let me know if anything needs to be added to the post).

What I am trying to do is deploy a .NET Core Web API with AWS Lambda. My API seems to be working locally, as I tested it (I have an Angular frontend app, with which I am able to successfully execute all the APIs). However, when I deploy with AWS and run a few of the APIs on Postman, I get a "502 Bad Gateway" error.

My `serverless.yml` file looks like this:

```
service: angularawardwebapi

provider: 
  name: aws
  runtime: dotnetcore2.1
  region: us-east-1

package:
  artifact: bin/release/netcoreapp2.1/deploy-package.zip

functions:
  api:
    handler: angularawardwebapi::angularawardwebapi.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync
    events: 
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
```

My Model Class looks something like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace angularawardwebapi.Models {
    public class Student {
        [Key]
        public int StudentId{get;set;}

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName="nvarchar(50)")]
        public string StudentFirstName{get;set;}

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName="varchar(50)")]
        public string StudentLastName{get;set;}
    }
}
```

My DbContext file looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseContext:DbContext {
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options):base(options) {

        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students {get;set;} 
   }
}
```

I have two methods in my Controller:

```
        [HttpGet("temp")]
        public ActionResult<List<String>> GetTemp() {
            return Ok("here");
        } 


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>> GetStudent()
        {
            return Ok(_context.Students);
        }
```

The first of which works without a hitch (as expected). However, when I try to return a list of the Students that are in the DB, it seems that I'm encountering issues.

I tried using the second API locally as well, and received the appropriate response:

```
[
    {
        "StudentId": 1,
        "StudentFirstName": "John",
        "StudentLastName": "Doe"
    }
]
```

I also checked the AWS CloudWatch Logs, which showed something like this:

```
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting GET https://[myurl]/dev/api/Student/ 
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Route matched with {action = "GetStudent", controller = "Student"}. Executing action WebApi.Controllers.StudentController.GetStudent ([myprojectname]) 
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Executing action method WebApi.Controllers.StudentController.GetStudent ([myprojectname]) - Validation state: Valid 
[Information] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure: Entity Framework Core 2.1.8-servicing-32085 initialized 'DatabaseContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None 
END RequestId: f57417d3-4075-4680-a78d-e90e2c710760
REPORT RequestId: f57417d3-4075-4680-a78d-e90e2c710760  Duration: 6006.80 ms    Billed Duration: 6000 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB   Max Memory Used: 141 MB 
2019-06-06T14:19:41.116Z f57417d3-4075-4680-a78d-e90e2c710760 Task timed out after 6.01 seconds
```

This time out issue is not seen when I run the API locally, as I immediately get the correct response (as specified above).

---

### **Update**

So I now have an RDS Database, which I can successfully connect to and play around with in SSMS. Running APIs locally also still work. However, after I deploy it using `serverless deploy -v`, I'm still facing the previous issue. As suggested, I tried modifying the permissions for the DB, although I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing there either. What I've done is:

- Went into SSMS and modified the database permissions by right-clicking the server, going to Permissions, selecting my login (that I set up while configuring the RDS), and granted the "Alter any database" option. I then went to the database itself and modified some permissions (Delete, Insert and Update).
- I also enabled the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In) Windows Firewall rule.

Neither of these seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: How many Students are there in your production DB versus your local DB?

Comment: Right now, I'm using my local DB for both.

Comment: What led me to that question: The DB doesn't seem completely unreachable, otherwise the Error would be different. Timing out smells like the DB needs too much time to transmit the result - as would be the case if you had like a huge number of hits for example. How do you host your DB? On AWS or somewhere completely different?

Comment: Thank you! I think I have to set up my DB instance and everything with Elastic Beanstalk first, right? Then follow the same procedure that I did for setting up my local db.

Comment: @Fildor Thank you for your earlier help. I'm still running into the issue, but for seemingly different reasons. As per my conversation with carlos chourio below, I have now created an RDS database and updated my .NET code to connect to it. However, I'm still running into the time out issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the same connection string you used for testing in your local Db, you should change it to use some database that the api can access to from aws. 
If that's the case then your api is trying to access to a local db (which obviously it's not going to find), that would explain the timeout issue.

In order to fix it you should probably deploy your database to AWS as well and change the connection string of the project to the connection string of that database inside of AWS.

Comment: So the issue persists. I have now set up an RDS Database and modified my connection string to connect to that. Playing around with it locally yields the correct results, so I have configured it correctly. However, once I deploy it with `serverless deploy -v` and try the same, it results in the same time out as before.

Comment: Did you check that you're allowing the database to be connected by the api? You'd probably need to set up some permissions ir order to be connected

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. How would I set that up? I already have an IAM token set up with the project, but that doesn't seem to be the only issue.

Comment: I don't think I can help you with that, I've answered because I've had the same issue when deploying an API to Azure, but I'm not familiar with AWS. In azure you have to go to the firewall settings and enable the **Allow access to azure services** option. AWS should have a similar configuration. You could also add a rule to the firewall that lets you connect from the ip of the web api and check if it works